# Possibly upgraded Windows 7 to Windows 10, but Win7 product key still works?

Tags: windows-7, windows, product-key

I wish to install Windows 7 on my mac. I had a copy of Win7 years ago, and I believe I allowed the automatic upgrade to Win10 to happen, on my current PC. Tonight I entered my old Win7 product key here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows7
...and it validates, and allows me to download a Win7 disc image file.

Questions are... 1) Shouldn't that product key have expired for Win7? 2) Is there any scenario where my Win7 product key might be available to use (unassigned)?

Thanks for any advice in advance. I'm just trying to get a totally legal Win7 installation, wouldn't mind paying.

Comment: Windows licenses never expire.  However, OEM licenses cannot be transferred to new equipment, which would not be applicable to a license running on Apple hardware (Apple isn’t a Microsoft OEM) so it cannot and does not sell OEM Windows licenses.  So given you license is a Retail license, can be migrated to another machine, and activated on that hardware.  What is your question?

Comment: I upgraded from Win7 to Win10 on my PC, and I'm basically wondering if there is any way the original Win7 license is actually usable again for the new Win7 installation. It's a really stupid question right?...

Comment: Windows licenses are never revoked by Microsoft.  Perhaps the only exception might be extreme cases of piracy.  There are existing questions that cover this subject.  Which I will look for shortly